# Why is x 1 when assigning a double?

Tags: c#

I'm very new with C#.

I don't understand why is x = 1 and not 1.4.

Can please somebody explain me this?

```
double x = (double)(12 / 5 - 3 % 2);

Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is NOT about double.

You are integer-executing

(12 / 5 - 3 % 2);

and THEN casting to double. If you want this to be about double, then make sure at least one of the numbers is a double. In your case just mark the literals as double.

(12d / 5d - 3d % 2d);

is all doubles. As long as one is a double, the operation happens as double - but your original case makes all the calculations, THEN casts to double. So they happen as integer.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing integer math and *then* converting to double. 12 / 5 = 2, 3 % 2 = 1, and 2 - 1 = 1.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! :)

The problem is that you are operating all int, and afterwards converting them to double.

You need to make sure that you are operating with doubles from the beginning.

Try out the code in here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xaQjKL

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Doubles from the beggining
        double d_twelve = 12.0;
        double d_five = 5.0;

        double x = (double)(d_twelve / d_five);
        Console.WriteLine($"Using all doubles: {x}");

        // First split two int, then convert the result to double
        int i_twelve = 12;
        int i_five = 5;
        x = (double)(i_twelve / i_five); 
        Console.WriteLine($"Using ints, and converting at the end to double: {x}");


        // And now your code:
        x = (double)(12 / 5 - 3 % 2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Your original code: {x}");

        // And now your code fixed (notice the 12 => 12.0):
        x = (double)(12.0 / 5 - 3 % 2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Changing 12 by 12.0: {x}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing operations with integers and then casting he result to a double.

```
double x = (12d / 5d - 3d % 2d);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Adding d after a number will make it a double while adding f will make it a float.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals

Answer (score 0):

Because you use integer values inside the parenthesis, and the expression is calculated using integer math before being cast to double.

You can use a double value for the first value and it should be enough:

```
> double x = (12d / 5) - (3 % 2);
> Console.WriteLine(x);
1.4
```